# Ionic ngOpenFB login not completing with no errors

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, facebook-login

Im using ngOpenFB on Ionic, and Ive got my callback set to localhost:8100/oauthcallback.html

```
$scope.submit= function () {
    ngFB.login({scope: 'email'}).then(
    function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            alert('Facebook login succeeded');

        } else {
            alert('Facebook login failed');
        }
    });
 }
```

When I hit submit, the oauthcallback.html window gets opened, and in the url I see the valid access token.  However, neither of the alerts fire.  Theres is no success, and no failure.  Just a blank oauthcallback.html page, with the access token in the URL.

I know I can use some trickery to just get that token from the URL and close the window myself.  But surely this should be automatic in the ngOpenFB library?

Like it should do it for me no?? Store in sessionStorage, and close the window.

Otherwise, if I don't solve this, Im just going to do it the hacky way, and get the token, and save it myself.

But any ideas on why its not working as it should?

Comment: Yes, it's the ngOpenFB library that do the work normally. Have you put this in oauthcallback.html : `<script>
    window.opener.openFB.oauthCallback(window.location.href);
    window.close();
</script>`

Comment: I figured out the issue.  I had two oauthcallback.html pages, one in my root, which was empty.  and one in js, which had what you just posted above.  Im just tired. lol  After screwing around with the hack I mentioned above, and getting it all working.  I realized my error, and facepalmed